# Hexadecimal as Delimiter in a textfile

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to load a text file with hexadecimal 19 as a delimiter in Hive.

It is not loading table properly. All the columns are loaded in the first column of the table.

I have tried using different values `\u0019` or `^Y` as fields terminated by.

Any thoughts on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try **octal**, like in all the Hive tutorials?? See the examples in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL (although no-one thought to remind readers that on Unix/Linux, an initial `0` implies _octal_ >>  `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\031' STORED AS TEXTFILE` should do the trick.

Comment: I just loaded as csv file and it looks good. Thanks for your response..